# How to get the property(id, CSS, xPath) of a popup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing

I have a disturbing popup that breaks automation test. It is client side validation popup appended to a textfield that only takes number, if I input a text and click the submit button, the popup will suddenly appear and stop the test. How do I overcome this? Appreciate. It is the one having a yellowish bos with exclamation mark, that reads "Please enter a number". When I viewed the source of the page, I found nothing to reference on this popup.
[image: Popup obstructs automation test]

Comment: When you say *suddenly* does that mean at any stage of the test? Or, you know where? And, what browser are you using?

Comment: When i click on the "Sign In" button

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve. I mean what are the steps your automation test should perform. It would be great if you could also post the HTML.

Comment: What I want is to be able to skip / stop this popup. Had it been it is possible to see the id/CSSPath/xPath I'll code the test to continue when it pops up.

Comment: Is it a pop up window? Can you provide some html?

Comment: Sorry, not a popup window. It is a textfield validation popup. It is the one with yellow icon on the image I posted.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have mentioned it is not a pop up window I think switching the focus to the activeElement should be sufficient.

```
Driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();
```

Comment: Though I'll give it a shot but it's not a popup window, just a popup for textfield validation. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't. Stil pending.

Comment: @kehinde Can you provide me the `html` of the element?

Comment: <input name="institutionCode" type="number" id="institutionCode">

Comment: Try `By byId = By.Id("institutionCode");

            IWebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(_webDriver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(byId));
            element.Clear();
            element.SendKeys("TestInsCode");` Replace the _webDriver instance with the driver instance you are using

Answer (score 1):

The popup appears because the text you put in the input field of "Institution Code" is a letter (o) while it expects a number.
Basically, your script puts the number of the "Institution Code" into the Username field.
Try correcting the Strings that you send.

For negative tests, if you want to get rid of the popup, you need force the input value of the "Institution Code" to be a number and then trigger onBlur() event. This way, the validation would pass.

Comment: I think you got a better understanding of what I'm trying to do. I'll appreciate if you can provide a code snippet to reinforce your suggested implementation.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? to bypass the popup under what circumstances?
A possible scenario would be:
- intentionally type letter; check popup presence; correct input value to be digit; check popup doesn't show again;

Answer (score 1):

First, it's good idea to put also your testing code, because I think the main problem will be there. But If you would like to remove this yellow warning popup:

Add to your submit button attribute "**formnovalidate**"

f.e.:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" formnovalidate />
```

This warning popup is native browser HTML5 validation invoked by submit action.

**Reference:**

- https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-novalidate

Comment: Thanks. In anyway, I did not write the application I'm only assigned to write the test for it, so I have no control to edit the file. Adding that would indicate incompetence to the developer.